# Spring Data MongoDB Repositories Query multiple fields

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here is my document:

```
@Document(collection = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String description;
}
```

I'm trying to query for posts with title or description with a like operator.
My Repository

```
public class PostsRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ $or: [ { 'title' : ?0 }, { 'description' : ?0 } ] }")
    Page<Post> queryByTitleOrDescription(String query, Pageable pageable);
}
```

How do i perform this query with LIKE on both fields with an or between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So to answer my own question, this is the solution I came up with, if someone knows something which is more performant I'd appreciate it (I believe text search is not applicable since it doesn't work with partial words)

```
@Query(value = "{ $or: [ { 'title' : {$regex:?0,$options:'i'} }, { 'description' : {$regex:?0,$options:'i'} } ] }")
    Page<Post> query(String query, Pageable page);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can even go without any explicit query declaration if needed:

```
interface PostRepository extends Repository<Post, String> {

  // A default query method needs parameters per criteria

  Page<Post> findByTitleLikeOrDescriptionLike(String title, 
                                              String description,
                                              Pageable pageable);

  // With a Java 8 default method you can lipstick the parameter binding 
  // to accept a single parameter only

  default Page<Post> findByTitleOrDescription(String candidate, Pageable pageable) {
    return findByTitleLikeOrDescriptionLike(candidate, candidate, pageable);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it using the regex by default and not performing a full text comparison?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries

Comment: Super! Thanks a bunch.